# How to add mat-tab pagination to a horizontal mat-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab, mat-list

[image]

Can anyone suggest a good way to implement the pagination functionality you see above, found in `<mat-tab-header>` on a horizontal `<mat-list>`.

I don't need to use `<mat-list>`, I just figured this was the most obvious container.

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz?

Comment: @HGPB I'm also looking for the same. Please share if you got any solution. Thanks!